# OPE Kac-Moody Currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, wick-theorem, affine-lie-algebra

> We have the following operators:
>   \begin{align}
> J^a(z) = \frac{1}{2}\psi_s^{\dagger}(z)\sigma^a_{s s'}\psi_{s'}(z), \hspace{10 mm} \bar{J}^a(z) = \frac{1}{2}\psi_s^{\dagger}(\bar{z})\sigma^a_{s s'}\psi_{s'}(\bar{z})
> \end{align}
>   of the right and left -moving SU(2) Kac-Moody algebras (here$ a = x,y,z$ and $s, s' = \uparrow, \downarrow$,
>   \begin{align}
> [J^a(x),J^b(x')] = \frac{-i}{2\pi}\delta^{ab}\delta'(x-x') + i\epsilon^{abc}J^c(x)\delta(x-x')
> \end{align}
>   Using the OPE for the fermionic operators $$<\psi_s^{\dagger}(z)\psi(z')_{s'}> = <\psi_s (z) \psi_s^{\dagger}(z')> = \frac{\delta\delta'}{2\pi(z-z')}$$ derive the OPE for the Kac-Moody currents $J^a(z)$ ($\textit{Hint:}$ use $\sigma^a\sigma^b = \delta^{ab} + i\epsilon^{abc}\sigma^c$)
>   \begin{align}
> :J^a(z)::J^b(z'): ~=~ \frac{i\epsilon^{abc}J^c(z)}{2\pi(z-z')} +\frac{\delta^{ab}}{8\pi^2(z-z')^2} + \dots
> \end{align}
>   and the same for the $z \rightarrow \bar{z}$ and $J^a\rightarrow \bar{J}^a$ (left-right symmetry).

I've tried some basic stuff, but it is not clear to me how I should begin this problem.

Comment: Just try to write $:j(z)::j(w):$ as $stuff + :j(z)j(w):$. The stuff will be the OPE. So the prerequisite for doing this exercise is understand OPEs and definition of Normal Ordering.